# CSS border not showing up?

Tags: html, css

So, in my CSS code, I have the following:

```
img {
        border: 5px solid #fff;
        margin: 5px;
        position:relative;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
        -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
        box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px #ccc;
            opacity: 0.5;
         filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* For IE8 and earlier */
```

However, the 5px white border is not appearing, just the shadow. What am I missing?

Edit: In response to all replies thus far, I obviously see that #fff is white, as I mentioned above, the "5px white border". I want it to be white.

What's happening is that there is **NO** border showing up at all, just the img with a shadow. But I want the 5px white border, then the shadow fall off of that. I've seen it elsewhere but for some reason it's not working for me.

Comment: I did include the ending } tag, just missed it on here.

Comment: I doubt this is a UX question, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your image has a border. You used `#fff` as the border color which is the HEX code for `white`. Change it to `black` or something darker.

Answer (score 1):

change your color of `border: 5px solid #fff;` to something like `#000`.Your are not seeing border color because `#fff` denotes white color and your body background color is also white.

Answer (score 0):

Your img has a border, but you can't see it since #fff is white (unless you've got a darker background).